# 'jQuery' is undefined in IE only

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a html file which works perfectly in all the browsers other than IE. In IE I am getting an error

```
   SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

But this issue can be fixed by opening this file say index.html in any eitor and save it in different name. But if I save this file as index.html itself, issue will not be fixed.

Can any one let me know what is this issue?!!

Comment: What is the version of IE you are using?

Comment: Iam using IE10 but in all versions the issue persists. I got this html from a zip file.

Comment: What is the version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have used `application/javascript`, change to `text/javascript`
2. Check the path of jquery
   is your jquery in `lib/js/`, or just `lib/`?
3. Make sure your lib directory is relative to the calling page
   You may have meant `/lib/jquery.js` (the slash in the beginning makes a difference).

May this will help.There is a link from [Jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-is-undefined-ie-only).