# jquery datatables fails to display in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a web app that uses jquery tabs and jquery datatables.  Works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but in IE, all I see is a list of the tab names.

When I look at the browser debugging tools I see "'jQuery' is undefined" in jquery.dataTables.js, line 40.

```
else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable ) {
```

Here's where I load the jquery.dataTables

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: i have checked this:-https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html    in IE 5 to 11 working fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780047/jquery-is-undefined-in-ie-only

Comment: IE 11.0.9600.18537

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code. Will be easy to debug and help you

Comment: I use datatables heavy in ie. I do not have any issues specific to the IE browser.  We would like to see some code.

Comment: Do you have jquery being loaded before datatables?

Comment: I got it working but I'm not sure why.  The previous developer had a downloaded jquery.dataTables.js file he was using.  I forced it to use a url instead.  That caused new problems so I put it back the way it was.  Then lo and behold, it worked in IE.  Really wierd.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  It worked on the test server but when I deployed to the production servers, the error occurred again.  Both are using tomcat.